# How can I make LinqPad show me all results without the need to "click" "List<T>" hyperlink to get the query to execute?

Tags: linqpad

I am having an issue getting LinqPad to exapnd and/or execute  a layer of my Dump().

Specifically I am using GroupBy and projecting a new object which contains the group.Key, and group.ToList() collection.

The Query executes fine, and the data is displayed...

Where I have my group.ToList(), it shows List< T > which I then have to click on to see the results.  (I can click and see the results I'm looking for, but I need them without the click)

How can I make LinqPad show me all results without the need to "click" the "List< T >" hyperlink to get the query to execute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's tricky to replicate your problem without any example code. Have you tried the overloads of the `Dump()` extension that take a `Depth` parameter?, e.g. `Dump(int depth)` or `Dump(string description, int? depth)`.

I'm not sure what the default depth is so it might not solve your issue, but it'll make the difference between something like (for example) - some test data with `.Dump(2)`:

[image]

and some test data with `.Dump(3)` (as if you'd already clicked on the `IGrouping` above):

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  Soon as I added the depth the data came through as expected :)